# Faces won't appear regardless of it being in wireframe or solid

Tags: wireframe

[image]

So as you can see the faces are there, but the object is not in wireframe. It is in solid. How do I make it so the faces appear? I have tried alt+H and pressing z too many times to count.

Comment: perhaps in the Object menu > Display > Maximum Draw Type, switch from Wire to Solid?

Comment: @moonboots omg thank you I saw that on a different post and I couldn't find display in the object menu so I ignored that idea. Turns out I was looking in the wrong object menu. I thought it was the drop down object menu on the view/select/add/object bar so yeah my bad sorry

Comment: @cegaton yes but their question is possibly very misleading so in case anyone has this question in the future it is best to leave this question up so they actually get the answer they’re searching for.

Answer (score 6):

In the *Properties > Object menu > Display > Maximum Draw Type*, switch from *Wire* to *Solid*